# Dotplot chart for enrichment analysis

Tags: r, ggplot2, func, graph-visualization

I'm trying to do a dotplot with my KEEG analysis result for pathways, however, almost every script that has about it needs an FC value to perform the analysis. I don't have this value, because my data came from my miRNA analysis, which generated the targets and then I was able to establish the pathways. I would like to put the routes in a dotplot like this one in the imagem [image]

These are examples of my data:

[image]

I followed a script from a colleague here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=rf,y=pathway_term)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=pval,size=gene)) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5)) + 
  labs(x='Rich Factor', y=NULL, color='P-value',size='Gene\nnumber' ) + 
  theme( axis.title = element_text(face='bold'), axis.text = element_text (face='bold') )
```

However, the error appears: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale Could someone help me solve my problem?

Comment: Please share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: term enrichment pvalue count
EGFR tyrosine kinase inhibitor resistance 2,5 1,1E-09 20
MAPK signaling pathway 4,9 2,6E-09 39
ErbB signaling pathway 2,4 0,000000027 19
Proteoglycans in cancer 3,8 0,00000003 30
MicroRNAs in cancer 4,8 0,000000038 38
PI3K-Akt signaling pathway 5,1 0,00000014 40
Focal adhesion 3,4 0,00000095 27
Pathways in cancer 6,2 0,000002 49
Signaling pathways regulating pluripotency of stem cells 2,7 0,0000053 21
Glioma 1,8 0,000024 14